# Simple chrome extension opening new tab and showing data from page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to write a chrome extension, reading data from the `window` object of the current page, opening a new tab and showing the data there.

Do you know a simple example for that?

My current problem is that I can't write to the opended tab.

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Inspector",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions" : ["tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Inspector"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

`content.js`

Send a message with the document title to background.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                "message": "open_new_tab",
                "title": document.title
            });
        }
    }
);
```

`background.js`

Receives the title and try to write it to opended tab.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {
            "message": "clicked_browser_action"
        });
    });

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (request.message === "open_new_tab") {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    "url": "inspector.html"
                }, (tab) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        //use your message data here.
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.title = request.title"})
                    }, 3000)
                })
            }
        }
    )
});
```

`inspector.html`

Empty page.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need 2 scripts for this - Content Script, Background Script, apart from manifest.json

Process would be :-

1)Fetch the data from current page using content script.

2)Notify Background with the your data and pass as a message from content script.

3)Receive a new message in background script and create new tab with the message data.

For e.g. - Pass title from current page, and set in new Tab.

Content Script -

```
//send current window title to background js.
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'title': window.title})
```

Background Script -

```
//receive message
chrome.runtime.onMessage((message, sender) => { 
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'NEW URL'}, (tab) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //use your message data here.
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.title = message.title"})
        }, 3000);
    })
});
```

Comment: Still does not work. It seems `chrome.tabs.create` has no access to the `window` object. Already tried with `window.title = "foo"`. Added code snippets to my question.

Comment: You would require "tabs" permission to do this.
Add =>  permission : ["tabs"] in manifest.json.

Let me know if you still face any issue !!
Oh wait please, I am looking into the code.

Comment: Okay, my bad, in background.js you don't have access to window object for specific tab. 
You can do it by injecting js I have updated my answer.

Comment: Or You can again send the message from Background to Content Script, and there you have access to full "window" object.

Comment: `document.title` on the opended tab is empty. Still does not work. My goal is to read data from the current page, open a new tab and show it there. I can't find an example for that.

Comment: Okay,
I have created this extension for you, when you click that extension it grabs the title from current page, opens a new Page and shows same title in new tab with extra information (using full HTML)
You can download it from - https://files.fm/u/bx8zjxu4
Do let me know in case of any query/concern.